# htaccess redirect regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to write a regex to redirect JUST `http://www.domain.com/pages`, not for any other subdirectories like `http://www.domain.com/pages/page1`.

I was thinking about these 2 solutions, but as I am not good at writing regex, I can just describe it.

a) I need to write a regex, that will return true only if the searched sub-string `pages` is at the very and of an URL.

OR

b) I need to write a regex, that will return true only if the searched sub-string is exactly same as the URL, so I will search for `http://www.domain.com/pages`.

OR do you have any other ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as always with regexp's - `^` marks beginning of the string, `$` marks the end

```
RewriteRule ^/pages$ target [l]
```